# Rails 3.2.9/nginx/unicorn, old unicorn processes sticking around after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, unicorn

I just launched a new app on a 512MB VPS slice (Ubuntu 12.04). I'm trying out the nginx/unicorn stack for the first time, I more or less followed [Ryan Bates' Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) for the deployment, which went reasonably well.

After I deploy any changes with capistrano:

1. Changes I make to any erb files are not reflected in production, and
2. Seems like old unicorn processes are sticking around. When I try to hit the app I get a 500 error, and exception_notifier tells me that it's looking for the app in an outdated folder inside of /releases/

My **deploy.rb** file looks like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
     run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end
  # etc...
```

And my **unicorn.rb** file (based on the setup for zero downtime deploys):

```
preload_app true 

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  old_pid = "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

So far the only way to fix this issue is if I manually kill unicorn by doing `sudo kill 'cat /home/path/to/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid'` and then restarting it.

Is there a conflict between doing the unicorn restart in my deploy.rb, and the zero downtime deploy settings in my unicorn.rb file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**

I have made some progress. Looks like my tasks to start/stop/restart unicorn in my **deploy.rb** file were not doing the job. The start task *seems* like it might be working, but I believe unicorn requires more specific & targeted commands to kill and restart processes. I borrowed the code I found here https://gist.github.com/zires/1003099 and made some modifications:

Updated **deploy.rb**:

```
task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} start"
end

task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -QUIT `cat #{release_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`"
end

task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "kill -s USR2 `cat #{release_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`"
end
```

Stopping and restarting unicorn processes seems to work much better like this, and I can confirm brand new ones are spawned up after a cap deploy. I sincerely hope this helps someone out with this same issue, it was a frustrating one!

One question still remains though, does what I have in **deploy.rb** work in tandem with my **unicorn.rb** code to do a zero-downtime deploy? I can't tell, on my system during a deploy the load is so high (compiling assets and stopping & starting everything) that it kind of kills my server regardless... If anyone can shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but upgrade to rails 3.2.11 right away - http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/

Comment: What do your /etc/init.d/unicorn_* files look like?  For me, I've never had any luck performing a "restart" with Unicorn.  I always do a stop then start...

Comment: @house9 Thanks for the heads up! Hmm, looks like 3.2.11 introduced a bug "for all JSON-based API applications", oh man no too many positive comments going on in that post...

Comment: @CDub check out the update to my post. Try restarting using "kill -s USR2..." like I showed above.

Comment: Ah, okay.  To answer your new question, I believe that the deploy.rb file makes calls to your unicorn.rb, so in that case, it'd be serial.